# Sharing results of asynchronous call using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am new to JavaScript promises and would like to know if this is the common/idiomatic way of doing sharing results asynchronously in JavaScript/Node.js.

I have a method, say `calc`, that computes a list of items asynchronously. I only want the result to be calculated once, and other cals either get the already calculated results or wait until the result is calculated. I've come up with the following design (a minimal example to demonstrate it).

```
let result: Promise<number[]>;

async function calc(): Promise<number[]> {
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }

    result = new Promise<number[]>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await delay(5000);
        resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    });
    return result;
}

async function delay(time: number) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

Is there any flaws with this design? Is the `calc` method always asynchronous? i.e., the results run in a different stack than the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `calc` method always asynchronous?

*Consuming the result* from the promise `calc` returns will always be asynchronous (which is probably what you really mean). This is guaranteed by the specification: `then` and `catch` callbacks are always called asynchronously, whether the promise is already settled or not.

Note that if you're returning a promise (which you are in all code paths in `calc`) and not using `await` in the immediate body of `calc` (which you aren't), you don't need to declare `calc` as `async`. Doing so conceptually adds a layer of promises (which is largely harmless, but...).

> Is there any flaws with this design?

A couple of minor ones. `delay` is, of course, just standing in for the real work that you're going to do. Using `await delay();` in your `async` promise executor callback without a `try`/`catch` means you will miss it if the promise from `delay` *rejects*. You want to ensure you handle rejection (perhaps with a `try`/`catch` in the executor callback, or by not using `await` in it).

Related to that, the code is also falling prey to [the Promise creation antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Since `delay` provides a promise, here's no need for `new Promise` in `calc`. Just use the one from `delay`.

So `calc` could just look like this:

```
function calc(): Promise<number[]> {
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }

    return result = delay(5000).then(() => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}
```

Since you're explicitly handling the promise, I probably wouldn't use `async` on it.

Live Demo (just for fun; I've made the delay 800ms instead of 5000ms):

```js
let result;
function calc() {
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }

    return result = delay(800).then(() => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

console.log("A");
calc().then(() => { console.log("C"); });
console.log("B");
calc().then(() => { console.log("D"); });
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("E");
  calc().then(() => { console.log("G"); });
  console.log("F");
}, 1000);
```

As you can see, it outputs `A B`, waits 800ms, outputs `C D`, waits a further ~200ms, and then outputs `E F G`, proving that *consuming* `calc`'s promise is always asynchronous.

Comment: s/could/should :-)